# Recall command in GAP system

Tags: gap

Is there is a way to recall a command from the history on the Ubuntu GAP system prompt? (something like CTL-R on Linux systems). Basically I want to reuse a command that I typed before, but the only thing that I found is the Up arrow, which is very slow...

Many thanks.

Comment: This is a question about GAP, not about research-level mathematics.  For what it's worth, if you access GAP through a Sage notebook, as is probably easiest, then you can use the Sage notebook-editing capabilities.

Comment: I don't know about the version bundled in Ubuntu, but if GAP is [compiled with GNU readline support](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap6.html#X82234FD181899530) then the standard readline search functions (Ctrl-r and Ctrl-s) should be enabled. You can use the instructions shown on the manual page to check if your version of GAP is built with readline support. If the installation seems correct, but the key combo still doesn't work, it is best to reach out to [the experts](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap1.html#X7BF552C07E2F8F7C).

Comment: Many thanks @WillieWong I missed the ./configure with readline support. I am rebuilding GAP now and I hope it will work. will give you a feedback in few minutes. Could you please turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the version bundled in Ubuntu, but if GAP is [compiled with GNU readline support](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap6.html#X82234FD181899530) then the standard readline search functions (Ctrl-r and Ctrl-s) should be enabled. You can use the instructions shown on the manual page to check if your version of GAP is built with readline support. If the installation seems correct, but the key combo still doesn't work, it is best to reach out [to the experts](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap1.html#X7BF552C07E2F8F7C).

<sub>(Converted from comment)</sub>

Comment: I believe one shouldn't encourage off-topic questions. There are active forums dedicated to such questions.

Comment: @YCor: the [gap] tag has existed on MO since 2016, and is a software used in research mathematics. This question falls into what I consider a "gray area". While I accept and appreciate the difference of opinion on whether it is off-topic, I do not appreciate your lecturing tone in the previous comment.

Comment: Sorry for the tone, I just view it as expressing an opposite opinion. I'm aware of the Gap tag (I'm using SageMath so I'm highly supporting Gap). [Browsing this tag](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/gap) or other software tags, you'll see that questions there have some mathematical flavor. Sometimes the mathematical substance is low and we're in the "grey area". Here there's no mathematical contents at all.

Comment: Dear @YCor: Thank you for your response. My attitude is evidently more permissive. But since this is not about mathematics, I think it is fine to have a difference of opinion. Best.

Comment: FWIW, there are GAP tags at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gap (600+ questions) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gap-system (~40 questions) - and other support channels, mentioned at https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/gap/info.